# How to show different function usages when using varargin (...)?

Tags: matlab

When you type in a Matlab function name and open a brace (e.g. `sum(`) in the command window, a tooltip opens that shows all possible usages of this function.

When I write my own function that accepts `varargin`, the tooltip shows just one option, which instead of `varargin` puts `...` (e.g. `myfunc(x,...)`).

How can I suggest more specific usages of my function to the user?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Its already there. This works for any m-file on your search path.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: I recently discovered that tooltip for a function can be called by Ctrl+F1 in MATLAB editor. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

I can get you there without editing 'Syntax' that works on current releases, though a little muddy.

The below function takes a range of required, optional, and optional name-value pairs for inputs.  I want tool tip to give the user information on the required and optional inputs.  varargin always exists even if no variables are passed into it, and inputParser works pretty well when handed varargin.  I'm going to take advantage of this by leaving my optional inputs on the function call, but then stack them into varagin before I ever work with them.

tool tip will display myFun( frequency, gain_optional, phase_optional, ...)

```
function myFun( frequency, gain_optional, phase_optional, varargin )

%% Get mandatory and optional Inputs using inputParser
p = inputParser;

% mandatory inputs
argName = 'frequency';
validation = @(x) validateattributes( x, {'numeric'}, {'2d','positive'} );
p.addRequired( argName, validation );


% optional inputs

% start by packaging all optional inputs into varargin.  The two optional
% inputs were kept out of varargin so they will display in the tooltip
if nargin > 2
    varargin = [{phase_optional} , varargin];
end
if nargin > 1
    varargin = [{gain_optional} , varargin];
end

% add optional inputs into inputParser
argName = 'gainLinear';
default = [];
validation = @(x) validateattributes( x, {'numeric'}, {'2d','positive'} );
p.addOptional( argName, default, validation );

argName = 'phaseDeg';
default = [];
validation = @(x) validateattributes( x, {'numeric'}, {'2d','positive'} );
p.addOptional( argName, default, validation );

% name-value pairs
argName = 'model';
default = [];
validation = @(x) validateattributes( x, {'numeric'}, {'vector','positive'} );
p.addParameter( argName, default, validation );

argName = 'order';
default = [];
validation = @(x) validateattributes( x, {'numeric'}, {'scalar','integer','>',0,'<',3} );
p.addParameter( argName, default, validation );

% pull out all passed data with the inputParser and stash into input struct
p.parse(frequency, varargin{:});
input = p.Results
```

Answer (score 0):

One method, if you know the maximum number of variable inputs and all of their names, is to do something like:

```
function out = my_func(var1, var2, var3)

    if nargin < 1
        var1 = default_var1_value;
    end
    if nargin < 2
        var2 = default_var2_value;
    end
    if nargin < 3
        var3 = default_var3_value;
    end

end
```

When you do this, Matlab lets you call `my_func` with 0,1,2 or 3 arguments. But the tooltip will only have one entry:

```
my_func(var1, var2, var3)
```

This, to me, at least seems better than `...`. I have no idea how/if it's possible to make it display more than one tooltip.

**Edit:** It seems that built-in functions get some kind of extra privilege somewhere. For example, the function `rank` comes with Matlab and displays two tooltips. If you `edit rank`, copy the code into a new file `my_func.m`, and rename the function `my_func`, it only gets one tooltip. So it's not just some special formatting of the commented lines at the top.

Comment: Problem is that some vars can have different meanings (like most Matlab built in functions), and then this won't work.