# Multiple tooltip input suggestions for Matlab function

Tags: matlab, input, documentation

I notice on built in Matlab functions there can be multiple lines of possible input configurations like this

[image]

as opposed to just

[image]

I have to assume they use something akin to `inputParser` with the use of `varargin`, but I have been unsuccessful in trying to replicate this functionality. I would like to have the ability to do this but I'm starting to get the feeling this is only something you can do with built in functions.

Somethings that I have thought of or tried are:

1. Parsing of the help doc (unsuccessful)
2. Information in a separate file
3. Creating the same functions for multiple classes (unsuccessful)
4. Creating a fully functioning `inputParser` (unsuccessful)

Has anyone been able to do this?

Comment: Not possible at the moment, I once submitted a technical request since this behavior is linked to custom documentation creation, but it is not documented/supported. I tried to reverse engineer it without success. 
I can tell, that if you request thus functionality, and other people join, we might live to the day to see it documented/implemented.

Comment: Cool, good to know.
How exactly do you go about requesting functionality? Do you use the same system you do for reporting bugs?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/service_requests/contact_support.do?

Comment: Yep, I always got to that page and assumed that it was only bugs. Now I see it says suggestions as well.


Thanks a ton!

Comment: here's a somewhat relevant thread from Loren's blog http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/05/05/nice-way-to-set-function-defaults/

Comment: A closely related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412782/how-to-show-different-function-usages-when-using-varargin

Comment: @Macduff I'd argue that this is a duplicate of the question you linked to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show different function usages when using varargin (...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412782/how-to-show-different-function-usages-when-using-varargin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have built a similar tool in the past that works quite well. Unfortunately it's a proprietary in-house tool so I can't share the actual tool. However I can tell you that after investigating several options (similar to those you listed) we decided to use a special syntax for our help comments (similar to [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) or [restructuredText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText)) that supports the declaration of syntax  variants.

The information from the help texts is then parsed by the tool and can be displayed in different manners (e.g. by [shadowing the original `doc` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11262600/857390) with a custom one).

Regarding the actual pop-up menu you may try to dig into the internals of the command window. Yair Altman has documented many unofficial ways to enhance the MATLAB GUI on [his wonderful blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/). For example, [here's a post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-desktop-tab-completions/) that describes how to add tab-completion to custom commands.